# Eclipse CDT - Symbol `__RLIMIT_NPROC` could not be resolved

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse Mars CDT on Ubuntu 15.04 to write some C code.

Eclipse complains as below:

[image]

But it seems Eclipse knows `RLIMIT_NPROC` is expanded to `__RLIMIT_NPROC`. And I can use `Ctrl+Click` to jump to where `RLIMIT_NPROC` is defined, which is `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/resource.h`.

And in that file, **the `__RLIMIT_NPROC` is defined just one line above the macro declaration. How could eclipse find the `RLIMIT_NPROC` but not find the `__RLIMIT_NPROC`???** See below:

[image]

And my project `Inclueds` looks like this:

[image]

### ADD 1

Adding the following line can solve the symbol issue:

`#include <bits/resource.h>`

But the compilation failed with this:

[image]

I change to include the `<sys/resource.h>` as requested, the symbol issue shows up again...

Comment: If your code compiles without errors (i.e. outside of Eclipse) it just might be a bug in CDT

Comment: @szx I hate to say this is bug. But currently, I am inclined to believe so. And live with it. I am starting to miss the good old days when I was using Visual Studio.

Comment: given this comment in the resource.h file: "/* Transmute defines to enumerations.  The macro re-definitions are
   necessary because some programs want to test for operating system
   features with #ifdef RUSAGE_SELF.  In ISO C the reflexive
   definition is a no-op.  */"  a key question would be: What standard have you told the compiler to use?  `-std=c99` `-std=c11` `-ansi` if the standard is `-ansi` then that might be the source of the problem

Comment: @user3629249 I guess I didn't modify the default value for `-std`. Where can I check it?

Comment: @user3629249 I see some posts says it's at `Project Properties/Settings/C
Compiler/Miscellaneous/Other Flags`. But I simply don't see it in `Eclipse Mars CDT for Linux`.

Comment: If you're still seeing this with the latest version of CDT, please [file a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) with details.

Answer (score 1):

All works perfectly for me. I create "C project" (**File->New->C project->Hello world ANSI C project**) and insert this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(void) {
    struct rlimit t;
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, &t);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```